# creating dynamic bootstrap style with asp net web forms

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

i just created a pagination function that i need to be styled with css. the problem is that it does not take the class i want for some reason. here is my code:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SourceTech.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for pagination.
    /// </summary>
    public class SourceTechPager : Panel
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Renders the databind to aspx.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            CssClass = "Pagination"; //My css class

            base.Render(writer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Algorithm for paging.
        /// </summary>
        public override void DataBind()
        {
            Controls.Clear();

            var startLoop = CurrentPage - 2;

            var totalLoop = TotalPage;

            if ((TotalPage - 2) > 7)
            {
                totalLoop = (CurrentPage - 2) + (CurrentPage + 4);

                if (totalLoop > TotalPage)
                {
                    totalLoop = TotalPage;
                }
            }

            if (startLoop <= 1)
            {
                startLoop = 0;
            }

            for (var i = (startLoop); i < totalLoop; i++)
            {
                var lb = new LinkButton();

                if (TotalPage == 1)
                {
                    lb.Visible = false;
                }

                lb.ID = "Pager" + i;

                lb.CommandArgument = (i + 1).ToString();
            if (i + 1 == CurrentPage)
            {
                lb.CssClass = "Pagination"; //My css class
            }

            lb.Text = (i + 1).ToString();

            lb.Click += ((sender, args) =>
            {
                CurrentPage = int.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
            });

            Controls.Add(lb);
        }


        base.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

ASPX:

```
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <asp:SourceTechPager runat="server" ID="pagerId" CurrentPage="1" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.SourceTechPager .Pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pagerCssClass {
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

    .pagination > li {
        display: inline;
    }

        .pagination > li > a,
        .pagination > li > span {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #337ab7;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        .pagination > li:first-child > a,
        .pagination > li:first-child > span {
            margin-left: 0;
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        }

        .pagination > li:last-child > a,
        .pagination > li:last-child > span {
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        }

        .pagination > li > a:hover,
        .pagination > li > span:hover,
        .pagination > li > a:focus,
        .pagination > li > span:focus {
            z-index: 2;
            color: #23527c;
            background-color: #eee;
            border-color: #ddd;
        }

    .pagination > .active > a,
    .pagination > .active > span,
    .pagination > .active > a:hover,
    .pagination > .active > span:hover,
    .pagination > .active > a:focus,
    .pagination > .active > span:focus {
        z-index: 3;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: default;
        background-color: #337ab7;
        border-color: #337ab7;
    }

    .pagination > .disabled > span,
    .pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
    .pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
    .pagination > .disabled > a,
    .pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
    .pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
        color: #777;
        cursor: not-allowed;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
}

.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

I tried with hardcoding an integer "1" to my listitem tag, and that works fine with the style, but it does not for some reason once i place my control tag in it. what should i do?

Comment: Where is your `CurrentPage` coming from and is it definitely set? When you debug, does it hit the breakpoint on `lb.CssClass = "Pagination";` line?

Comment: Yes CurrentPage is my property. It's set there's no problem there. And yes, when I debug it hits the breakpoint.